# How to exclude entities that have isDeleted database field set to 0 from Hibernate Search results?

Tags: java, hibernate, search, hibernate-search

I implemented a searching system for a web app using Hibernate Search and it works well only that I want to exclude the entities that have the database field isDeleted=0. I found that this could be achieved using Criteria but in my case , isDeleted is not mapped to an attribute in my entity class.

Is there any way I could achieve this without modifying the entity class?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with java for a while, but I remember that there is a possibility to write explicit named query for the matter using annotation NamedQuery on class level. Examples of named queries are here - http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-named-query-examples/

I am not sure if it works without having the deleted flag mapped to attribute though, you would have to try it.